# Smallest circle containing a polygon with center inside it.

Tags: circles, polygons

Given a non-convex polygon P with holes. Is there a way to find the circle with the smallest possible radius containing P? Also center of circle must lie inside the polygon. Without last condition it would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest-circle_problem but now i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I would first solve the problem for the convex closure $\overline P$ of $P$, which in general will be of smaller radius than for your polygon with holes. If the center of that circle belongs to $\overline P \backslash P$, then of course it will be necessary to move the center to the boundary of $P$ in whichever way increases the radius the least, subject to the constrain of enclosing $P$.